# Search Folder not shown in outlook when Exchange Cache mode is enabled

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin

Below is my piece of code used to add a folder called "*All inbox items*" inside search folders in outlook. This code works all fine when an outlook setting "**Use Cached Exchange Mode**" checkbox is ticked (i.e. enabled).

```
public FolderId CreateSearchFolder(List<FolderId> listofFolderId)
{    
    try
    {
        // Create the folder.
        var searchFolder = new SearchFolder(Service) { DisplayName = "AllInboxItems" };

        var searchfilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, true);   
        searchFolder.SearchParameters.RootFolderIds.Add(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
        foreach (var entry in listofFolderId)
        {
            searchFolder.SearchParameters.RootFolderIds.Add(entry);
        }
        searchFolder.SearchParameters.SearchFilter = searchfilter;

        // Call Save to make the EWS call to create the folder.
        searchFolder.Save(WellKnownFolderName.SearchFolders);

        return searchFolder.Id;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {    
        return null;
    }
}
```

I wanted to know why this code fails when **Use exchange cached mode** setting is *enabled*. Is there anything that I am missing?